# $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and $[b-1,c]$ $\Rightarrow$ uniformly continuous on $[a,c]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and $[b-1,c]$ $\Rightarrow$
>   uniformly continuous on $[a,c]$

My thoughts:

Without loss of generality we only need to show that it's uniform if $x_1 \in [a,b]$ and $x_2 \in [b-1,c]$ (since we already know it's uniform if $x_1,x_2 \in $ the same set).

Using the definition of uniform continuity we know:

$|a-b|<\delta _1 \Rightarrow |f(a)-f(b)|<\epsilon /2$ for $[a,b]$

$|c-(b-1)|<\delta _2 \Rightarrow |f(c)-f(b-1)|<\epsilon /2$ for $[b-1,c]$

Combining we get:

$$|x_1-x_2|<|a-b|+|c-(b-1)|<\delta _1 +\delta _2 \Rightarrow |f(a)-f(b)|+|f(c)-f(b-1)|<\epsilon$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why is there a condition $a<b-1$? It still works if I take $a=b-0.5>b-1$.

Comment: Your proof is unclear at best. What does "for $[a,b]$" even mean?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD it's an interval from $a$ to $b$, assuming $a<b$

Comment: That's not what I asked. You wrote "$|a-b| < \cdots $ for $[a,b]$". What does that line mean? Don't you mean for some $x$ in $[a,b]$ or something like that?

Comment: Also, your proof is not complete. You are suppose to arrive at "$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon$".

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD yes so if I pick an arbitrary point from 2 different sets [a,b] and [b-1,c] I can always compound the uniform continuity. So if I pick $x\in [a,b]$ I can go from $x$ to $b$ and then from $b-1$ to any point $\leq c$

Comment: Pick $x_1$ and $x_2$ as arbitary points. Then I can do $|x_1-x_2|\leq |x_1-b|+|b-1-x_2|$

Comment: lol Why $b-1$ instead of $b$?

Comment: $|x_1-b|+|b-1-x_2|\leq |x_1-b|+|b-x_2|$ since $x_2\geq b-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I_1=[a,b], I_2=[b-1,c]$. Let $x\in I_1$, $z\in I_2$ and $y \in I_1\cap I_2$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, we know there exists $\delta_1,\delta_2$ such that *for every* $x,y,z$ (in the respective domains) we have,

\begin{align}
|x-y|&<\delta_1 \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac \varepsilon 2\\
|y-z|&<\delta_2 \rightarrow |f(y)-f(z)|<\frac \varepsilon 2
\end{align}

Now,

$$|x-z|\leq |x-y|+|y-z|<\delta_1+\delta_2 \rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(z)|<\varepsilon$$

But also, $|f(x)-f(z)|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(z)|$ by triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Is it possible to have the same argument without the intersection set? $|x-z|\leq |x-b|+|b-z| \leq \delta_1 +\delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(b)|+|f(b)-f(z)|< \epsilon$

Comment: Yes, I think that works too. I tried to remark that it didn't matter that the invervals were $[a,b]$ and $[b-1,c]$, we just needed their intersection not to be empty! :)